# Resize content of Region to fill entire region

Tags: layout, javafx

I'd like to create a layout container that has some of the features of `BorderPane` but without exposing BorderPane's methods (e.g. setCenter).

I'm thinking that one way to do this is to extend `Region` and set a BorderPane as its child:

```
class MyPane extends Region {
  private val borderPane = new BorderPane
  borderPane setCenter foo
  getChildren add borderPane
}
```

The problem is that now the BorderPane will not be resized to fill the Region. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Answered here: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2609674